# Not able to insert and delete images from Gallery on Android Sony devices

Tags: android

I have developed an application in which i am inserting and deleting the images from gallery. And it working perfectly on all android device except the sony devices.

Please help me out. How can is delete of insert images from gallery on sony android devices.

Comment: Please help me out. How can I delete or insert images from gallery on sony android devices.

Comment: can you please add your code here. It will help... are you using MediaStore ?

Comment: For deleting the below code i am using.

Comment: My code is working for all devices but it  is not working for Sony android device. For deleting the below code i am using.      
      File sourcefile = new File(galleryPath.split("DATE_TAKEN")[0]);
      File destinationFile = new File(folder.getAbsolutePath(),File.separator+fileName);
      if(!destinationFile.exists())
       destinationFile.createNewFile();
      sourcefile.renameTo(destinationFile);
 getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA+"=?", new String[]{galleryPath.split("DATE_TAKEN")[0]});

Comment: For inserting i am using below code.

Comment: File sourcefile = new File(vaultPath);
      File destinationFile = new File(galleryPath);
      if(!destinationFile.exists())
       destinationFile.createNewFile();

      sourcefile.renameTo(destinationFile);


      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
      values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, galleryPath);
      values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, dateTaken);
      getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

Comment: Yes i am using MediaStore.

Answer (score 0):

After Add File use following code

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(imageAdded)));
```

After Delete file use following code

getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null)

Comment: I have using the same, but it is not working on Sony android devices and same code is working other devices. Is there any other way?